# PHPWORD how can i use function addText without break

Tags: phpword

example:hello  world

i want to display above in one paragraph  without breakup

```
add Text("hello");    
add Image('image URL');    
add Text("hello");
```

in this way. there will be 3 breaks

which paragraph will influence the break?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHPWord addTextRun method's description](http://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elements.html)

With a textrun you can add text and textbreaks within one paragraph.

```
$textrun = $section->addTextRun();
$textrun->addText("hello");
$textrun->addImage('image URL');
//if you want to seperate the text
//$textrun->addTextBreak();
$textrun->addText("hello");
```

Comment: `addText()` inserts the Text in the new line when the we use `load()` before it to get contents from DOC file

Comment: `how can we put text in 3 separate lines in a table's cell?` kindly suggest.